# Is it possible to render modifiers at preview settings?

Tags: python, rendering, cycles-render-engine, scripting, modifiers

I have an issue where I am trying to render a very complex scene, and I need to cut on my poly count in order to fit it on my GPU. The simplest way is to change modifiers like Sub-division to a lower value, like in my preview, which is all fine and good, but I have hundreds of objects . . . is there a way to render at the Preview settings in the final render?
I do know rendering at these lower settings will work as my scene currently renders in the viewport, I just need to know if there is some Python script or something to set all final values to the preview values.

I am using:

- Blender 2.72
- Cycles Render Engine

Scene details (preview):

- 384,000 verts
- 366,000 faces
- 237 objects
- .45 GB Memory

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a option in the *Scene* tab of the *Proprieties* editor called *Simplify* that limits the maximum number of subdivisions on all objects. In the picture below all objects would be limited to just 2 subdivisions.
[image: Scene setting]