# Some modifiers don't work on appended object (Modifier's names are red highlighted)

Tags: append

When I append an object from a 'spare part' Blender file, its modifiers (SubSurf and boolean) don't work. Their names are highlight in red in the stack modifier.
Even if I remove those modifiers from the source file, I can not still apply them in the second file.

I've tried to set this object as Unique (U) or Local (L) in both files; nothing new!

Any idea about that behavior?
(Blender 2.74, W. XP)

[image: Modifier on appended object]

Comment: It's because Win XP.. You shouldn't use it. I mean it..like really. Ok the problem might be couple reasons, one of them Simplify set to 0 (under Scene). You should give us the .blend file.

Comment: Thanks Jerryno ! You're right, it WAS the simplify option of the scene.
I haven't use this fonction for now so I've learn something new.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn off subsurf modifier on a lot of objects at the same time](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27787/how-to-turn-off-subsurf-modifier-on-a-lot-of-objects-at-the-same-time)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to render modifiers at preview settings?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21053/is-it-possible-to-render-modifiers-at-preview-settings)

Comment: @David While those questions have answers which solve this question I would argue that those *questions* are very different. See http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/549/duplicate-answer-vs-duplicate-question

Comment: @poor see my comment to David.

Comment: @RayMairlot Thank you, I had forgotten about that post. Also here is another on the same subject http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213979/278094. I have retracted my CV.

Comment: @David This one might be a little closer (http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28468/subdivisions-view-parameter-using-multires-or-subsurf-modifiers-no-longer-increa/28484#28484) but even then I'm not sure (and didn't want to be biased towards something I'd answered)